# Avoiding redefinition of enums in C

Tags: c, enums

I need an explanation as to how to make this work (if it's even possible).

So, in my header file, I have an enum declaration for a BOOL type with some routines I am supposed to implement.

```
#ifndef _TABLE_H
#define _TABLE_H

typedef enum BOOL { false, true } Boolean;

#endif //_TABLE_H
```

I'm using this interface in a file that has a definition of various routines using the bool type (not Boolean this time)

```
typedef enum BOOL { false, true } bool;
```

I want to be able to use both, how do I do this?

Comment: Use `stdbool.h` for both and don't reinvent the wheel

Comment: Why are you redefining bool? why not include the header `#include <stdbool.h>` ?

Comment: This seems to be more a design issue; you seem to have two different types with the same semantics. This is not good.

Comment: so this is not possible, you'd say? @Codor

Comment: Why not drop one of the types?

Comment: I'm trying to understand how the "wheel" works/should work @StoryTeller

Comment: Then examine the standard header on your system. What you are really doing is entrenching a bad design decision in your code base.

Comment: Wheel is round, why are you making it square?

Comment: I was thinking of a situation where I'm implementing someone else's interface and I already have a bunch of routine using my enum type

Comment: @ekeith - This is precisely why such design decisions are bad. Since enums are not scoped, you have yourself a mess to resolve. Had the author of the library (and you) used `stdbool.h` this problem would go away. The standard gives us these tools to resolve such problems.

Comment: I understand the design aspect of it, being consistent. A yes/no answer is what I'm asking, assuming there's no stdbool.h lib or a library for everything, how can you resolve an issue like this? @StoryTeller

Comment: Separate all the code that sees the libraries symbols from your symbols. Use a stable type like `int` to go between. Not the most convenient or type safe. But at least you won't get redefinition errors.

Comment: Let's pretend you never mentioned `bool` or its variations.  How do you prevent duplicate definitions of `enum Colour { BLACK, BLUE, GREEN, CYAN, RED, MAGENTA, YELLOW, WHITE };`? Then you define the enumeration type in a header and protect it with header guards (not starting with `_` and a capital letter; that's reserved for the implementation), or perhaps `#pragma once`.  Like you did in the question.  And include that header whenever the code needs the colours.

Comment: I understand better now. Thanks @JonathanLeffler

Comment: What people are hinting about here is that a very long time ago, a boolean type was added to the C language. You need to update your C knowledge to include these language changes introduced a very long time ago. Summary of booleans: The C language boolean type is `_Bool` and it can hold the values `1` or `0`. The standard header `stdbool.h` holds defines such as `#define bool _Bool` together with `#define false 0` and `#define true 1`.

Answer (score 0):

In your provided code you are redefining `BOOL`. So, to avoid the redefinition of `BOOL`, do following when you are providing definition to `bool`:

```
typedef enum BOOL bool;
```

So you have followings:

*File1.h*

```
#ifndef _TABLE_H
#define _TABLE_H

typedef enum BOOL { false, true } Boolean;

#endif //_TABLE_H
```

*File2.h*

```
#include <File1.h>
...
typedef enum BOOL bool;
...
```

Here, you are providing definition for `BOOL` in `File1.h`. In `File2.h` you are just providing an alias name.
**Note:** It would be better if you just provide deceleration in `File1.h` and put definition of `BOOL` in some another file.